# How to add Search Icon next to my label?

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-4

Hi I am working in Angular 4 designing using bootstrap 4.
I tried to add search Icon at the end of my label.

Codings below:

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    <label class="Bold">Location Id </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="LocationId" >
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    <label class="Bold">Description </label>               
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```

but it comes like the attached image[image: Click here]. How to add icon at the end of label. Is any problem with my coding?

Comment: You can reduce col-lg-4 to col-lg-3 and create one div with col-lg-1 just below that one and put your search button inside that div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make use of **[input-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons)** component of bootstrap4

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Go</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, let say I  wanna add the above search icon within the   label-right side, how to do?

Comment: `<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
  <label class="Bold" name="Location">Location Id </label>
 <div class="input-group">
 <input  type="text" class="form-control"  name="LocationId"  aria-label="Location" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
 <div class="input-group-append">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
 <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
 </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>`  I tried ur one but not working for me ..it still come out of the label. I just wanna add like your exact answer so that the design looks nice with other labels

Comment: @Ben where do you want your search icon...? your code is working fine https://fiddle.jshell.net/seknqf6d/

Comment: yes here working properly, but in my page, it shows label and icon separately.. not like output in this  https://fiddle.jshell.net/seknqf6d/

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Wrap `input` and `span` to the `input-group`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="row ">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    <label class="Bold">Location Id </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="LocationId" >
      <span class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    <label class="Bold">Description </label>               
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I took 1st answer and it working for me..but this is same as first answer. As I tick right ans alrdy, I gave u up vote

Answer (score 0):

Form-control class for Input makes the text box occupy the entire width. We need to use input-group class to group input and any icon attached to it. Refer code snippet below for example:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I took 1st answer and it working for me..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code snippet:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
<label class="Bold">Location Id </label>
 <input type="text" class="location-txt form-control"  name="LocationId" >
 <span class="input-group-btn location-search">
<button class="btn btn-info btn-md" type="button">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.location-txt 
    width: calc(100% - 44px);
    float: left;
}
.location-search{ 
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I took 1st answer and it working for me..sorry